# O-notation on algorithms

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

Can anyone help me describing the o-notation on this matching algorithm. I believe it is O(n)^2 since it uses multiple if-statement, is this correct. I've attached the entire function, so you can see the calculate age, which is used in the algorithm.

Thank you in advance for looking at my question.

Comment: [big o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) keeps all parts inside of parentheses. btw, what is the loop doing, how look your data?

Comment: Based on the code shown so far, that's an `O(1)` algorithm.  I'm not sure why you would think it's O(N²).

Comment: Your loop unconditionally breaks at the end of its body if it is not broken before, so it will run exactly one time. Big O is all about scalability - i.e. time/space demands based on size or magnitude of input; what is your input? Without a defined input, Big O makes no sense.

Comment: You'll need to show the complete code, and define what input your algorithm has. The snippet you posted has mismatched parenthesis so it won't run at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely `O(1)`.

The for loop never repeats; no matter what, `break` will be encountered on the first pass through the loop.

All the `if` checks are static `O(1)` operations. Unless `calculateAge` is an `O(n)` operation, which sounds exceedingly unlikely, `calculateAge` is `O(1)` as well. Multiple `O(1)`s combined sums up to `O(1)`, and since the loop never repeats, that makes the whole algorithm `O(1)`.

Computational complexity stems from loops and nested loops, but there are no working loops in your code.

Answer (score 0):

0(1). only one loop. if calculate age is not recursion.